# My gradient decent is converging but curve is not fitting properly

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, octave

My Gradient Decent code is not working. I do not understand where i am doing wrong

```
close all;
clear all;
clc
xx=linspace(0,10,100);
y=xx.^3+rand(1,100)*10;
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(xx,y,'.');
hold on
x0=ones(1,100);
x1=xx;
x1=x1;
x2=xx.^2;
x2=x2;
x3=xx.^3;
x3=x3;
X = [(x0);
    (x1);
    (x2);
    (x3);
    ];
X=X';
y=y';
alpha=.00001;
m=100;
n=4;
iteration=30000;
J=zeros(iteration,1);
theta=zeros(n,1);
for itr=1:iteration
    temp=zeros(n,1);
    for i=1:n
        temp(i)=sum((X*theta-y).*X(:,i))*alpha*1/m;
    end
    theta=theta-temp;
    J(itr)=sum((X*theta-y).^2);
end
Y=theta(1)+theta(2)*x1+theta(2)*x2+theta(3)*x3;
plot(xx,Y);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(J);
```

[image: right one is cost function curve]

Left one is fitted curve right one is cost function curve.Cost function is converging faster.If i increase the number of iteration cost function output remains same but fitted curve changes.But if i do this

```
            temp(i)=sum((X*theta-y))*alpha*1/m;
```

code just works fine.

[image]

Comment: You may want to clean up your code a bit (e.g. get rid of the `clear` stuff and condense the code) and add some comments...

Comment: That cost function curve is misleading, look at the y-axis scale, it's huge! When it "converges", the value is still ~1600, but your plot makes it look near-zero. You've provided no context to why the updated definition of `temp(i)` is a problem - why can't you just use this if it gives the correct result?